# Get average of rows per group based on a condition - R / Dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, datatable

I have a `data table` as shown below:

[image]

I need to evaluate the `average` of the data for the column '`Value`' for each `entity` when `Test_Date > Job_End_Date` based on a user-provided '`count`'.

For ex., if the count=2, use two data points after the Test_Date > Job_End_Date to calculate the `average`.

I am using the below expression but not getting correct results:

```
WT <- dt%>%
  arrange(Entity,Test_Date)%>%
  group_by(Entity) %>% 
  select(Entity,Job_End_Date,Value,Test_Date)%>%
  summarise(jobenddate = first(Job_End_Date),Ave = mean(head(na.omit(Value[lag(cumsum(as.Date(Job_End_Date) <= as.Date(Test_Date)),
                                                                                                                          default = 0) > 0]), n), na.rm = TRUE))%>%
  ungroup()
```

if n=2 in the above example,

ave for A = 15.02  (only one value since the Job_End_Date)

ave for B = (29.71+19.41)/2 = 24.56

```
dput(dt):

structure(list(Entity = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), Job_End_Date = structure(c(1616198400, 
1616198400, 1616198400, 1616198400, 1616198400, 1616198400, 1616198400, 
1614988800, 1614988800, 1614988800, 1614988800, 1614988800, 1614988800
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Test_Date = structure(c(1581379200, 
1582502400, 1582934400, 1583452800, 1584057600, 1584576000, 1585094400, 
1578528000, 1579910400, 1596499200, 1615334400, 1618272000, 1586476800
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Value = c(13.8, 
14.3, 18.97, 14, 14.97, 14, 15.02, 31.16, 35.95, 19.41, 29.71, 
19.41, 29.96)), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: CodeMaster, please don't provide images of code or data, I'm not going to spend time transcribing data, especially when you have it textually somewhere. Please (as akrun suggested) paste the output from `dput(x)` where `x` is a representative and small sample of your full dataset; reduction may be in the number of columns or rows or both, depending on the data and context. If we only need a handful of the columns to get the point across, no need to go overboard and give us all. Thank you.

Comment: added the dput!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the `arrange`, `filter` the rows where 'Test_Date' is greater than 'Job_End_Date', grouped by 'Entity' get the `mean` of `head` of 'Value' with `n` specified as 'count'

```
library(dplyr)    
count <- 2
dt %>%      
   arrange(Entity, Test_Date, Job_End_Date) %>%
   group_by(Entity, .drop = FALSE) %>%
   filter(Test_Date > Job_End_Date, !is.na(Value)) %>%       
   summarise(Avg = mean(head(Value, count), na.rm = TRUE))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#   Entity   Avg    
#   <chr>  <dbl>
#1 A       15.0
#2 B       24.6
```

---

Or another option is to use the logical expression within `summarise`

```
dt %>%
    arrange(Entity, Test_Date, Job_End_Date) %>%
    group_by(Entity) %>%
    summarise(Avg = mean(head(Value[Test_Date > Job_End_Date], 
            count), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: I only get the results for the entity 'B' and not 'A'...

Comment: @CodeMaster I think your Dates have typo for last row of A `7 A      2021-03-20 00:00:00 2020-03-25 00:00:00  15.0` May be the second one is 2021 instead of 2020

Comment: what if the average for an entity is null, but I still want to display the results in the resulting dataframe.. It seems the filter statement takes out any entity that does not satisfy the condition...

Comment: @CodeMaster the `.drop= FALSE` make sure that you have NaN value for that case

Comment: @CodeMaster I added one more option